# How do I use a button duplicated in my style in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, firemonkey

I've created a style with the Bitmap Style Designer for Delphi XE7.

I've updated the button style to white with a blue border and duplicated it to create an orange button called Button_Copy.

I've exported the style to FireMonkey, but I can't find Button_Copy to assign it to a button on my form. How do I do this?

Also, can I rename Button_Copy to e.g. OrangeButton?

Answer (score 0):

- In the Bitmap Style Designer, save the style as a FireMonkey style.
- Add a TStyleBook to your form.
- Set the StyleBook property to the stylebook.
- Double-Click the StyleBook and open your style. Close and Apply.
- You can now set the StyleLookup property of a button to Button_Copy and if all is well you will see your new style.

Note that your new style won't appear in the selection list for StyleLookup - the list of available values appears to be hard coded.

And, of course you can change the name - just change the StyleName property of the top level object (probably a TLayout). The normalnaming convention is to append the word 'style', e.g. OrangeButtonStyle.